# Resetting ARKit coordinates

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I have a simple question. If I wanted to start a game and place the board right in front of me:

```
gameBoard!.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, -0.6)
```

This works until I leave the game and come back again. Can I show the game board in exact same position in front of camera or `0.6m` in front of me? I might have physically moved to another position.

Comment: You need to place the gameBoard 0.6m from where the camera is looking. Either reset the camera, or calculate the position of the board based on the camera's position.

Comment: @AllenHumphreys My app freezes when this happens. Have you seen any documentation for this?

Comment: My comment was based on working with SceneKit, but my assumption is that ARKit has a notion of a camera very similar to SceneKit.

Comment: @AllenHumphreys can you give me a sample code of how to reset camera or position?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to reset you ARSession, you have to pause, remove all nodes and rerun your session by resetting tracking and removing anchors.

I made a reset button that does it whenever i want to reset:

```
@IBAction func reset(_ sender: Any) {

    sceneView.session.pause()
    sceneView.scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (node, stop) in
        node.removeFromParentNode()
    }
    sceneView.session.run(configuration, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
}
```

Or put it in your session was interrupted function!

Comment: This seems to work fine. I put the reset in UIApplicationWillEnterForeground notification though, so every time the user comes back it will reset the game board position.

Answer (score 2):

This should be possible using the option [resetTracking](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsession.runoptions/2875727-resettracking) when you call `run` on your `ARSession` again.

Example:

```
if let configuration = sceneView.session.configuration {
    sceneView.session.run(configuration,
                          options: .resetTracking)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*"This works until I leave the game and come back again."*

You can't track camera position in the background. Whenever your app goes to the background and camera turns off, you're losing your position, and [sessionWasInterrupted(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessionobserver/2891620-sessionwasinterrupted) will be called.

> A session is interrupted when it fails to receive camera or motion
>   sensing data. Session interruptions occur whenever camera capture is
>   not available—for example, when your app is in the background or there
>   are multiple foreground apps—or when the device is too busy to process
>   motion sensor data.

Comment: how do you reset the camera?

Comment: @slimboy What do you mean? Camera resets automatically, after app returns from the background.

Answer (score 1):

To reset ARSession in ARKit framework is quite easy:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate, ARSessionDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var arView: ARSCNView!
    @IBOutlet weak var sessionInfoLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        configuration.planeDetection = [.horizontal, .vertical]
        arView.session.run(configuration)
        arView.session.delegate = self
    }
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        arView.session.pause()
    }
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        guard let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else { 
            return 
        }
        let plane = Plane(anchor: planeAnchor, in: arView)
        node.addChildNode(plane)
    }
    func sessionInterruptionEnded(_ session: ARSession) {
        resetSessionTracking()
        sessionInfoLabel.text = "ARSession's interruption has ended" 
    }
    private func resetSessionTracking() {
        let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        config.planeDetection = [.vertical, .horizontal]
        arView.scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (childNode, _) in
            childNode.removeFromParentNode()
        }
        arView.session.run(config, options: [.removeExistingAnchors, 
                                             .resetTracking, ])
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.