# ARKit: How to reset world orientation after interruption

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I'm trying to get the ARWorldTracking session to re-orient north after a session interruption. I've went over the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsession.runoptions/2875727-resettracking) a few times but I'm finding it confusing.

**Current Behavior:**

When I lock the device and reopen the app, triggering the `sessionWasInterrupted`, the SCNNodes all shift counterclockwise on the compass by ~90 degrees or so.

> When you call the run(_:options:) method with a configuration of a
>   different type than the session's current configuration, the session
>   always resets tracking

I interpreted that as saying that when I generate a new set of configurations that is different from the `viewWillAppear`, the session will "reset". I'm not getting what is actually happening, but the orientation after interruption is off. (and 
`removeExistingAnchors` does nothing)

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration()
    configuration.planeDetection = .horizontal
    configuration.worldAlignment = .gravityAndHeading   
    sceneView.session.run(configuration)
}

func sessionWasInterrupted(_ session: ARSession) {
    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration()
    configuration.planeDetection = .horizontal
    configuration.worldAlignment = .gravityAndHeading
    self.sceneView.session.run(configuration, options: [ARSession.RunOptions.removeExistingAnchors, ARSession.RunOptions.resetTracking])
}
```

**Desired Behavior:**

When the app detects a session interruption, I'd like it to re-orient itself back to true north.

Answer (score 8):

This issue was killing me, too - you helped me out with half the solution - adding the 'Reset tracking / Remove existing anchors' flags was the magic key for me - I think the other half is the guidance from [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45105684/reset-arkit-coordinate) where you have to pause your session and remove all the nodes from the scene, then re-position them.  The combination of both of these things got the compass to reset back to True North after session interruption for me.

```
func resetARSession() {
    // Called by sessionInterruptionDidEnd

    sceneView.session.pause()
    sceneView.scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (node, stop) in
        node.removeFromParentNode() }
    setupARSession()
    setupSceneView()
}

func setupARSession() {

    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    configuration.worldAlignment = .gravityAndHeading
    sceneView.session.run(configuration, options: [ARSession.RunOptions.resetTracking, ARSession.RunOptions.removeExistingAnchors])

}
```